# Product gets wrong url on product page

Tags: magento2.2, redirect

The product im having problems with has the url: 1-troy-ounce-silver-maple-leaf-6

in the backend the product has the URL key: 1-troy-ounce-palladium-maple-leaf

The product needs to have the URL key from the backend.

There are no custom redirects made in the magento backend, only the redirects magento has made from product category to URL.

I have indexed the site multiple times, refreshed the Redis cache and refreshed the Magento cache.

Am i missing something?

Comment: have you looked at the url_rewrite table? that is what counts

Comment: I have and cant see the old url in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check all the url rewrites under **Marketing --> SEO & Search --> URL rewrites**. You will propable have an old rewrite there. You can edit the current rewrite or delete the current one and create a new one. Be sure that under the **"SEO"** tab in the product itself it has the right `url-key`

Comment: glad we could help!